# Expression in Case When Clasue doesn't work in MySql query

Tags: mysql

I write bellow query in MySql 5.7, NUMBER_TRADE_ type is double, but  all value of RE is '1'.

```
SELECT 
    NUMBER_TRADE_, 
    (CASE NUMBER_TRADE_
        WHEN (NUMBER_TRADE_ = 0) THEN '0'
        WHEN (NUMBER_TRADE_ > 0) THEN '1'
    END) RE
from CANDLE_STICK;
```

Result of query:

```
----------------------
| NUMBER_TRADE_ | RE |
----------------------
| 0             | 1  |
| 1             | 1  |
| 1             | 1  |
| 0             | 1  |
| 0             | 1  |
----------------------
```

Comment: `CASE NUMBER_TRADE_` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove `NUMBER_TRADE_` after `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
    NUMBER_TRADE_, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN (NUMBER_TRADE_ = 0) THEN '0'
        WHEN (NUMBER_TRADE_ > 0) THEN '1'
    END) RE
from CANDLE_STICK;
```

because your code as it is compares `NUMBER_TRADE_` to the boolean expressions `NUMBER_TRADE_ = 0` and `NUMBER_TRADE_ > 0`.
You could simplify your code like this (if there is no case `NUMBER_TRADE_` to be negative):

```
SELECT 
    NUMBER_TRADE_,
    CAST((NUMBER_TRADE_ > 0) AS CHAR(1)) RE
from CANDLE_STICK;
```

or even:

```
SELECT 
    NUMBER_TRADE_,
    (NUMBER_TRADE_ > 0) RE
from CANDLE_STICK;
```

if there is no problem for `RE` to be an integer. 
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef3225af393a3269c95f755dd3ff6ebf).
Results:

```
> NUMBER_TRADE_ | RE
> ------------: | -:
>             0 |  0
>             1 |  1
>             1 |  1
>             0 |  0
>             0 |  0
```